# How can I get two form fields side-by-side, with each legend above the field?

Tags: html, css

**Problems:** I am currently having two problems with the form I am trying to do:

1. I am trying to have two forms side by side and I am stuck on how to achieve this with some css.

   The following is how the form currently looks:

[image]

I am trying to put the "or Search by Zip Code" section to on the right hand side of the "Search By Provider Credentials" form.

The following is the css I am using and html I am using:

```css
.form-style-5{
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset{
    border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 textarea,
.form-style-5 select {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    background-color: #e8eeef;
    color:#8a97a0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus{
    background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select{
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    height:35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
    background: #FF9900;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #FF9900;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height:55px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:hover
{
    background: grey;
}
.formSpacing{margin-top:10px;}
.inputWidth1{width:80% !important;}
.inputWidth2{width:70% !important;}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="number">1</span> Search By Provider Credentials </legend>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
<label class="formSpacing" for="job">Provider Name</label>
<input class="inputWidth1" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Provider Name *">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:20px">
<label for="job">Provider Speciality</label>
<select id="job" name="Specialty">
<option value="">Select a Specialty *</option>
<option value="PCP">Primary Care Physician</option>
<option value="Pediatrics">Pediatrics</option>
</select>  
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
<label class="formSpacing" for="job">Gender</label>
<select id="job" name="Gender">
<option value="">Select a Gender *</option>
<option value="PCP">Male</option>
<option value="Pediatrics">Female</option>
</select>  
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:55px">
<label for="job">City</label>
<select id="job" name="City">
<option value="">City *</option> 
 <cfoutput query="cityFind">
  <option value=#city#>#city#</option>
  </cfoutput> 
</select>  
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="number">2</span> or Search by Zip Code</legend>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
<label class="formSpacing" for="job">Zip Code</label>
<input class="inputWidth2" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Zip Code *">
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;  margin-left:20px">
<label for="job">Select Distance</label>
<select class="inputWidth2" id="job" name="Specialty">
<option value="">Select Distance *</option>
<option value="5" <cfif dist IS 5>selected="selected"</cfif>>5 Miles</option>
    <option value="10" <cfif dist IS 10>selected="selected"</cfif>>10 Miles</option>
    <option value="15" <cfif dist IS 15>selected="selected"</cfif>>15 Miles</option>
    <option value="20" <cfif dist IS 20>selected="selected"</cfif>>20 Miles</option>  
</select>  
</div>

</fieldset>

<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:15px">
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:85px">
<input type="button" value=" Clear " onClick="ClearForm()">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

2. I am trying to figure out a way, in javascript, to run a different script depending on which input is selected. If the user selects any of the inputs in the "Search By Provider Credentials", then run a particular script, otherwise run the other script.

How can I achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: also i found a small bug in your html.
<label class="formSpacing" for="job">Provider Name</label>
<input class="inputWidth1" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Provider Name *">
you are saying the label is for element with id of "job" but it should be for input field that follows the label.
to fix it, add an id attribute to the input element and then reference that id in the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#cred input, #cred select").change(function() {
  // Do what credential search needs
  alert("credential");
});
$("#zip input, #zip select").change(function() {
  // Do what zip code search needs
  alert("zip code");
});
```

```css
enter code here .form-style-5 {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset {
  border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 textarea,
.form-style-5 select {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  height: 35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
  background: #FF9900;
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FF9900;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 55px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:hover {
  background: grey;
}
.formSpacing {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.inputWidth1 {
  width: 80% !important;
}
.inputWidth2 {
  width: 70% !important;
}
.form-style-5 > form > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-style-5">
  <form>
    <div id="cred" style="display: inline-block;">
      <fieldset>
        <legend><span class="number">1</span> Search By Provider Credentials</legend>

        <div style="display: block;">

          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <label class="formSpacing" for="job">Provider Name</label>
            <input class="inputWidth1" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Provider Name *">
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:20px">
            <label for="job">Provider Speciality</label>
            <select id="job" name="Specialty">
              <option value="">Select a Specialty *</option>
              <option value="PCP">Primary Care Physician</option>
              <option value="Pediatrics">Pediatrics</option>
            </select>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div style="display: block;">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <label class="formSpacing" for="job">Gender</label>
            <select id="job" name="Gender">
              <option value="">Select a Gender *</option>
              <option value="PCP">Male</option>
              <option value="Pediatrics">Female</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:55px">
            <label for="job">City</label>
            <select id="job" name="City">
              <option value="">City *</option>
              <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                <option value=#city#>#city#</option>
              </cfoutput>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

    </div>

    <div id="zip" style="display: inline-block;">

      <fieldset>
        <legend><span class="number">2</span> or Search by Zip Code</legend>

        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <label class="formSpacing" for="job">Zip Code</label>
          <input class="inputWidth2" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Zip Code *">
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block;  margin-left:20px">
          <label for="job">Select Distance</label>
          <select class="inputWidth2" id="job" name="Specialty">
            <option value="">Select Distance *</option>
            <option value="5" <cfif dist IS 5>selected="selected"</cfif>>5 Miles</option>
            <option value="10" <cfif dist IS 10>selected="selected"</cfif>>10 Miles</option>
            <option value="15" <cfif dist IS 15>selected="selected"</cfif>>15 Miles</option>
            <option value="20" <cfif dist IS 20>selected="selected"</cfif>>20 Miles</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </fieldset>

    </div>

    <div style="display: block;">
      <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:15px">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:85px">
        <input type="button" value=" Clear " onClick="ClearForm()">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

1.
This should result in what you need, the changes were some added divs around the parts of the forms and two lines of css to get the right side of the form in place and enlarge the holding div as the form got wider. If you see it in one column use the full page in the snippet preview as the preview width might not be enough to hold the form width.

2.
I added some JavaScript, but without more information it might not be what you need, as it runs when you actually change something and it uses jquery.

Comment: Thank You so much for your help. For my understanding, to detect a field in the form, I would need to create id's or would it be possible to use classes as well? And what I am trying to do is when the search button is selected, it runs a script that will retrieve the data based on which fields was used. So based on what I am seeing on your example, it appears it will work

Comment: Yes classes work as well and you can create ids or classes for the container and use a selector to apply the detecion on the proper elements.

Comment: @ Peter Nemethy: Okay that makes sense. So based on how you did it, it should be able to retrieve a function as well correct. so I would do something like the following:                                                          $("#cred input, #cred select").change(function() {
  // Do what credential search needs
  example1();
});
$("#zip input, #zip select").change(function() {
  // Do what zip code search needs
  example();
});

Comment: @RobertoFlores Yes that is correct, and altough i didn't test your example it should work.

Comment: @ Peter Nemethy: I have tried that way but it does not work. No results occur. So what I did was I called the function SubmitMe when the search button is pressed and will run SubmitMe function will run only if any fields in the Search by Provider is selected, Otherwise, call another function. Here is what I did:                                              $("#cred input, #cred select").change(function() {
  // Do what credential search needs
  SubmitMe();
});
$("#zip input, #zip select").change(function() {
  // Do what zip code search needs
  SubmitZip();
});

Comment: @ Peter Nemethy: I figured it out. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of putting the two fieldsets side by side is having a container with a width, both fieldsets inside that container (div) and then setting

```
width: 50%;
float: left;
```

that will bring them side by side, but it might break your layout within the fieldset if the container width is too small.
Also you should add an element with `clear: both` applied or you can add `overflow: hidden` to the container

For second problem, the simplest solution i can think of (and requires no javaScript) is to separate the form into 2 forms (and have 2 separate submit buttons). then each form has its own action.
If you do want to have only one submit button you need to decide the rules on what field(s) are deciding which script gets called and writing them in a function that gets called on submit. The problem i see with this approach is, what do you choose for when user fills data in both fieldsets (or some data from one fieldset and some from the other).

[plain JS onsubmit example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)

[jquery .submit docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

EDIT - some more information about submitting the form to 2 different locations, based on user input.
I'm going to assume you are using jQuery as well. If you are not, you don't need to add it just for this small part, as it should be fairly similar also in plain JS.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default form submit action
    var firstFormHasData = false;

    //here goes all the checking e.g. (check if some option is selected in #job select
    if($("#job").val() !== "") {
        firstFormHasData = true;
    }

    //other similar checks for other fields
    //...

    //decide what action to take
    var action = "path/to/action2.php";
    if(firstFormHasData) {
        action = "path/to/action1.php";
    }

    //submit the form
    $("form").attr("action", action).submit();
```

EDIT2 - just realized you could simply add one class to all form elements in first part and another to all form elements in second part (or also just leave it without that class). Then attach the "change" listeners to all your form elements and when something is changed you can check if that element has first class and act accordingly.
example you decide to add class "first-part" to all elements in first part of form then code would be:

```
$("input, select").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("first-part") {
        //change the form action to be first action
        $("form").attr("action", "path/to/action1.php")
    }
    else {
        $("form").attr("action", "path/to/action1.php")
    }
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my questions, any fields in "Search By Provider Credentials" will run, let say script 1. Otherwise, run the other script for "or Search by Zip Code" because most likely one of those fields were selected. I am not sure how to call each field

Comment: edited the answer to include an example of how you could manipulate the form action attribute based on input values on submit, but now i realized that you could simply also change the action attribute when user changes a field and not need to modify the submit functionality. will include that in answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your second fieldset in a div element with an id, or class. preferably an id. Optionally give your body css a width...Float the field-form-5 to the left, and float the newly created div to the right. Adjust widths as needed.

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
     <style>

     /*option body width*/
     body {
     width: 1100px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     }
     /*Added div tag to second fieldset*/
     #right-side {
     width: 500px;
     float:right;
     }
     .form-style-5{
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background: #f4f7f8;
      margin: 10px auto;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #f4f7f8;
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
      float:left;
     }
     .form-style-5 fieldset{
      border: none;
     }
     .form-style-5 legend {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
     } 
     .form-style-5 label {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 8px;
     }
     .form-style-5 input[type="text"],
     .form-style-5 input[type="date"],
     .form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
     .form-style-5 input[type="email"],
     .form-style-5 input[type="number"],
     .form-style-5 input[type="search"],
     .form-style-5 input[type="time"],
     .form-style-5 input[type="url"],
     .form-style-5 textarea,
     .form-style-5 select {
     font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
     border: none;
     border-radius: 4px;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin: 0;
     outline: 0;
     padding: 7px;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box; 
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
      background-color: #e8eeef;
     color:#8a97a0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     </style>
</html>
<body>
<div id="left-side"> <!--NEW DIV OPTIONAL -->
<div class="form-style-5">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><span class="number">1</span> Search By Provider Credentials </legend>

        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <label class="formSpacing" for="job">Provider Name</label>
                <input class="inputWidth1" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Provider Name *">
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:20px">
            <label for="job">Provider Speciality</label>
                <select id="job" name="Specialty">
                    <option value="">Select a Specialty *</option>
                    <option value="PCP">Primary Care Physician</option>
                    <option value="Pediatrics">Pediatrics</option>
                </select>  
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <label class="formSpacing" for="job">Gender</label>
                <select id="job" name="Gender">
                    <option value="">Select a Gender *</option>
                    <option value="PCP">Male</option>
                    <option value="Pediatrics">Female</option>
                </select>  
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:55px">
            <label for="job">City</label>
                <select id="job" name="City">
                    <option value="">City *</option> 
                        <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                            <option value=#city#>#city#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                </select>  
        </div>
</div>
</fieldset>

<div id="right-side"> <!-- DIV FOR FLOATING CONTENT RIGHT.-->
<fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">2</span> or Search by Zip Code</legend>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <label class="formSpacing" for="job">Zip Code</label>
            <input class="inputWidth2" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Zip Code *">
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;  margin-left:20px">
        <label for="job">Select Distance</label>
            <select class="inputWidth2" id="job" name="Specialty">
                <option value="">Select Distance *</option>
                <option value="5" <cfif dist IS 5>selected="selected"</cfif>>5 Miles</option>
                <option value="10" <cfif dist IS 10>selected="selected"</cfif>>10 Miles</option>
                <option value="15" <cfif dist IS 15>selected="selected"</cfif>>15 Miles</option>
                <option value="20" <cfif dist IS 20>selected="selected"</cfif>>20 Miles</option>  
            </select>  
    </div>
</fieldset>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:15px">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:85px">
        <input type="button" value=" Clear " onClick="ClearForm()">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

I messed up one of your styles by accident, but i'm sure you can fix it.